Defining mutually recursive types in Coq?
Suppose I have types A,B,C,D,E,F. One of the constructors of A takes an argument with type F; a constructor of B requires A, a constructor of D requires arguments of types C and A, E requires D and F requires E. How should I define them?
I searched on the internet and found that I can use the keyword "with" to link them, but it doesn't work for me. Type C is a function type between two previous types that are not any of the 6 types listed above. When I try to use "with", somehow the arrow in the definition of C is highlighted, and I was shown the message Syntax error: '.' expected after [gallina] (in [vernac_aux]).
My code roughly follow this structure:
Inductive A : Type :=
  | a : F -> A
  | ... (other constructors unrelated to the problem)
 
with B : Type :=
  | b: xxx -> A -> B -> B
  | ...

with C : Type := xxx -> yyy
with D : Type := 
  | d : C -> xxx -> zzz -> B -> D
  | ...
with E := list D
with F : Type :=
  | f : E -> F
  | ...
.


Make a small example with two types and one constructor each (this will probably be meaningless, but it will probably go through syntax and type verification), then add constructors one by one, possibly add arguments one by one, you will see where the mistake highlights, and you will be able to post a question with a minimal working example, if need be.

Regarding C, you have to give names to the constructors, and the constructors should take some (zero or more) arguments and return something of type C.
So C should be like
Inductive C : Type := c1 :(xxx -> yyy) -> C.

Same for E.
Variable (xxx yyy zzz :Type).

Inductive A : Type :=
  | a : F -> A
 
with B : Type :=
  | b: xxx -> A -> B -> B

with C : Type := c1 :(xxx -> yyy) -> C

with D : Type := 
  | d : C -> xxx -> zzz -> B -> D

with E := e1: list D -> E
with F : Type :=
  | f : E -> F
.



In this case C is not a function between xxx and yyy, but its constructor takes such a function as argument.
If you want it to be definitionally equal to xxx->yyy, just do
Definition C := xxx -> yyy. 

and use that in your code instead.

If I use Definition C := xxx->yyy then how do I make F and A mutually recursive? C is in the long chain of dependencies and I can't take it out as a definition. Do I have to make C an inductive datatype then?

Do you mean that C takes an argument of type A? If so then its definition should be in the big mutually inductive definition. If I misunderstood please give an example.

Sorry for the confusion, I forgot that I can place the definition of C before other types, so I thought that I have to somehow place the definition in between other types. This shouldn't be an issue anymore.

However I don't want E to be an inductive data type. I just want E to be a list of D, and all other definitions remain. How should I do that?

Hm, in your code above, E is not the same Type as a list of D, but a completely different Type.  The only constructor to construct values of type E is the constructor e1 which takes as an argument a list of D.  If someone gives you a value of type E you can destruct it to get the list of D that was used to create it, but E itself is not the same type as list D.   If you just want E to be an "alias" for list D, then you do Definition E := list D.  But I have a feeling thats not what you want?

Alias is what I want in the case of E, but I don't know how to do that since the definition of E depends on D, and D is in this circular dependence. I cant just write Definition E := list D before A or after F, and I don't know how to write it in the middle.

You could just write list D instead of E (which you will define later), since they are definitionally equal.  E is then not a different type from list D. E is just a name tied to the "value" "list D" (yes, types can be values for type variables), and Coq's type resolution will accept both  f (nil : E) and f (nil : list D)
